# Can the Alternative Hypothesis be a specific number?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, self-study

I have the following homework problem. Im confused as to what to do if the alternative hypothesis is an equality. I have never encountered something like this until this problem. Should i just take it as >0?

[image: Homework]

Comment: Could you please add a reference to the textbook where this exercise appears?

Comment: Is $\beta_1^*$ the omitted variable biased estimate of the $X_1$ coefficient when not controlling for $X_2$? If not, please define.

Comment: Given the way the exercise is written $\beta_1^*$ is a fixed positive given number. As for instance $\beta_1^*=10$.

Comment: This is not in a textbook, it is a homework problem the Professor assigned us. And i think Xi'an is correct, at-least that is how a classmate and I have interpreted it, hence why I am confused.